# Retain Fragment. Пересоздание

Tags: android

Где сохраняется **retain fragment** во время пересоздания **Activity**?

Answer (score 1):

У всех активити есть метод `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance`. У `FragmentActivty` он переопределен. В нем сохраняются фрагменты.

```
 /**
     * Retain all appropriate fragment state.  You can NOT
     * override this yourself!  Use {@link #onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance()}
     * if you want to retain your own state.
     */
    @Override
    public final Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
        if (mStopped) {
            doReallyStop(true);
        }

        Object custom = onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance();

        FragmentManagerNonConfig fragments = mFragments.retainNestedNonConfig();

        if (fragments == null && mViewModelStore == null && custom == null) {
            return null;
        }

        NonConfigurationInstances nci = new NonConfigurationInstances();
        nci.custom = custom;
        nci.viewModelStore = mViewModelStore;
        nci.fragments = fragments;
        return nci;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

У активити есть метод onRetainNonConfigurationInstance(), внутри которого в объект класса NonConfigurationInstances сохраняются Retain фрагменты, вьюмодели из архитектурных компонентов и кастомные объекты (которые можно задать, переопределив метод onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance()

При пересоздании активити система в методе attach() возвращает в том числе и этот экземпляр NonConfigurationInstances.

Answer (score 1):

Retain фрагменты сохраняются в методе
[onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentActivity#onretainnonconfigurationinstance)

Answer (score 0):

Николай, retain fragment сохраняется в методе onRetainNonConfigurationInstance(). Данный метод вызывается системой в момент изменения конфигурации. В нем нужно вернуть объект типа NonConfigurationInstances.

Comment: Ты не имеешь тут силы писать - ты Ios разраб

Comment: ... который знает где сохраняется retain fragment